# Node.js refusing connection in mobile browsers

Tags: angular, express, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup a website on aws ec2 server. Angular-Express node.js-mongodb.
I have set up the website and its working properly in desktop, however when I am trying to connect to the site using cellphone browser, node.js is refusing connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

I did not find much online, I tried setting up port from localhost to 127.0.0.1, still same error.

Is it any other configuration I need to add in my api to make it mobile browser accessible. I am new to node.js. My application is working as expected on desktop.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require("../app");
var debug = require("debug")("ap1server:server");
var http = require("http");

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "4000");
app.set("port", port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port, "127.0.0.1");
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === "string" ? "Pipe " + port : "Port " + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + addr.port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
}
```

Following is my nginx config

```js
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # angular app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/front-end;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

Comment: There might be the issue with firewall of your ec2 instance, but I am curious about how its accessible from desktop. Can you try passing "0.0.0.0" in the listen method instead of localhost?

Comment: I have tried that, it did not work. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Link from desktop is working properly. In app, browser is making call to UI and UI connects to api via localhost/127.0.0.1, perhaps I should try to host api seperately on different port? I dont understand why it works for desktop and not for cellphone.